# Routes not working in navbar in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a navbar component in my react app using tailwindcss for styling. I have imported `react-router-dom@6.6.1` and tried to set up routes but can't get my pages/routes to show up.

[image: app structure]

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./routes/Home.js";
import About from "./routes/About.js";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route path="/About" element={<About />}></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home page

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-black text-3xl">Home</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I would expect to see `Home` appear on the `"/"` route when I click on the home link on the navbar and the same for `About`. However, I don't seem to be returning any routes.

About page:

```
const About = () => {
  return <h1>About Wick House</h1>;
};

export default About;
```

Navbar

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <header className="w-full fixed top-0 left-0 bg-slate-400 h-14">
      <nav className="md:flex items-center justify-between px-[8%] ">
        <div
          className=" text-base cursor-pointer flex items-center
      text-white gap-4 pt-2"
        >
          <img
            src="/wickhouse-logo-192x192.png"
            className="w-10 rounded"
            alt="Wick House Publishing Logo"
          />
          <h1>WICK HOUSE PUBLISHING</h1>
        </div>

        <div
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          className="text-3xl text-white absolute right-[8%] top-3 cursor-pointer md:hidden"
        >
          <ion-icon name={open ? "close" : "menu"}></ion-icon>
        </div>

        <ul
          className={`md:flex md:items-center md:pt-2 absolute md:static md:bg-slate-400 bg-slate-600 md:z-auto z-[10] left-0 w-full md:w-auto md:pl-0 pl-[8%] md:transition-none transition-all duration-500 ease-in ${
            open ? "top-14 " : "top-[-490px]"
          }`}
        >
          <li className=" md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0 my-4">
            <Link
              to="/"
              className="text-white hover:text-gray-300 duration-500"
            >
              HOME
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className=" md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0 my-4">
            <Link
              to="/About"
              className="text-white hover:text-gray-300 duration-500 md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0"
            >
              ABOUT
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className=" md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0 my-4">
            <Link
              to="/Authors"
              className="text-white hover:text-gray-300 duration-500 md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0"
            >
              AUTHORS
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className=" md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0 my-4">
            <Link
              to="/Contact"
              className="text-white hover:text-gray-300 duration-500 md:ml-8 text-base md:my-0"
            >
              CONTACT
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I have tried the documentation, guides, youtube and can't figure it out.

Comment: Check the console, do you see any error?

Comment: Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.

Comment: Where are you rendering another router? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Finally fixed the problem, i needed to make the navbar sticky as the content was being rendered behind it. Routes working properly.